# Why AVG SafePrice was added to Chrome when AVG is removed since long lime?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, avg-antivirus

I had a free version of AVG antivirus on my Windows 10 machine that I removed a half a year ago.

Today I opened Chrome with another profile and I mentioned that `AVG SafePrice extention was added to Chrome`.

[image: Printscreen with Chrome extension added]

This extension was removed immediately. The question is how to catch the spy process that added it to Chrome?

After uninstalling of AVG I ran full scan with Windows Defender Antivirus: nothing was found.

UPDATE 
As suggested, I ran Chrome with `--enable-extension-activity-logging` and tried to see activity log of this newly added extension but unfortunately it's empty

[image]

Comment: Same thing happened to me, SafePrice installed itself to Chrome without asking me, even though I have not been using AVG for a long time. This is virus-like behavior, absolutely unacceptable and I will complain loudly about this in public. Did you ever find out what "service" installed the extension?

Comment: No, I looked to Chrome's Activity Log but found nothing

Answer (score 2):

View the [Activity Log](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/23/google-chrome-activity-log-for-extensions/) of Chrome.

> Load chrome://extensions/ in Google Chrome to display all installed extensions.
>
> Click on the Details link next to the extension that you are interested in.
>
> Select the "View Activity Log" option on the page.

What was going on immediately before that (those) event(s)? Look there for the app which added the crudware.